# Applying % number format to a cell value using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to apply the % (percentage) number format using open XML C#

I have numeric value 3.6 that I want to display that number in excel as `3.6%.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
  WorkbookStylesPart sp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
```

Create a stylesheet,

```
 sp.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
```

Create a numberingformat,

```
sp.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats = new NumberingFormats();
// #.##% is also Excel style index 1
```

```
NumberingFormat nf2decimal = new NumberingFormat();
nf2decimal.NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(3453);
nf2decimal.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("0.0%");
sp.Stylesheet.NumberingFormat.Append(nf2decimal);
```

Create a cell format and apply the numbering format id

```
cellFormat = new CellFormat();
cellFormat.FontId = 0;
cellFormat.FillId = 0;
cellFormat.BorderId = 0;
cellFormat.FormatId = 0;
cellFormat.NumberFormatId = nf2decimal.NumberFormatId;
cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);
cellFormat.ApplyFont = true;

//append cell format for cells of header row
sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.AppendChild<CellFormat>(cellFormat);


//update font count 
sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)sp.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ChildElements.Count);


//save the changes to the style sheet part   
sp.Stylesheet.Save();
```

and when you append the value to the cell have the following center code hereonversion and apply the style index
in my case i had three style index hence the 3 one was my percentage style index i.e 2 since the indexes start from 0

```
string val = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(value)/100);
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(val);
cell.StyleIndex = 2;
row.Append(cell);
```

Comment: This flow worked for we can have have any cell formatting using this process.  Thanks ssyladin

Comment: No worries.  Actually spend ~30 minutes trying to do the formatting "manually" with OpenXML only and eventually gave up.  Kept on getting a corrupt worksheet.  So this is a good answer to me, since it helps avoid external library dependencies.

Comment: Does your comment about the Excel style index mean that, if you want to use the default Excel percent styling, that you don't need to add a new format, just set the cell to style index 1?

Comment: Has the `NumberFormatId` 3453 a special meaining or can I freely choose the ID?

Comment: @Selwyn Not working for me , excel getting corrupted .

Comment: Same is happening for me. I get a corrupted error and no formatting with this method. I also had to add a new CellFormats() to the sp.Stylesheet just to avoid a null reference exception.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately there isn't a straight-forward answer.  If you download the OpenXML Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office, you can dissect a simple spreadsheet and see how it formats the number.  To do just what you want you would need to:

- Create a StyleSheet
- Add a new NumberFormat with your custom definition
- Create a CellStyleFormat, complete with Border, Fill, Font all defined, in addition to the NumberFormat above
- Create a CellFormats, which refers to the above
- Finally set your Cell's StyleIndex to the ID of your CellFormat which uses the NumberFormat.

WHEW!

A generally better option is to look at ClosedXML at http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ (horrid name).  It's an open source (NOT GPL! - check the license) library that puts useful extensions on OpenXML.  To format a cell of a worksheet, you'd instead do:

```
worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = "0.036";
worksheet.Cell(row, col).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";
```

(from http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Styles%20-%20NumberFormat&referringTitle=Documentation )

---

**UPDATE**
ClosedXML has moved to GitHub at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: this may work, however requires a third party addition, not 'plain' OpenXml.

Answer (score 6):

Excel contains predefined formats to format strings in various ways.  The `s` attribute on a cell element will refer to a style which will refer to a number format that will correspond to the percent format you want.  See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730152/what-indicates-an-office-open-xml-cell-contains-a-date-time-value) for more information.

Here is the CellFormat object you will need to create in order to have the 0.00% mask applied to your number.  In this case you want the predefined format number 10 or 0.00%:

```
CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat(){ NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)10U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyNumberFormat = true };
```

Here is a quick way to insert the CellFormat into the workbook:

```
CellFormats cellFormats = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Elements<CellFormats>().First();
cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
uint styleIndex =  (uint)cellFormats.Count++;
```

You will then need to get the cell that has the 3.6 in it and set it's `s` attribute (StyleIndex) to the newly inserted cell format:

```
Cell cell = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().SingleOrDefault(c => cellAddress.Equals("A1"));
cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a simple way. If you want to apply it on single cell then do this,

```
worksheet.Cell(9, 10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#,##0.00\\%";
```

And If you want to apply it on a Range of Cells then do this,

```
worksheet.Range(9, 10, 15, 10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#,##0.00\\%";
```

you can also find more formats [Here](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumberFormatId%20Lookup%20Table&referringTitle=Styles%20-%20NumberFormat/), and also you can find the same from Excel  as well.

Comment: This is not OpenXml as indicated on the question.

Comment: Your backslashes saved my life :) Thanks.