# ClosedXML: Working with percents, 1 decimal place and rounding?

Tags: c#, rounding, decimal, closedxml

I am attempting to use C# and `ClosedXML` to enter data into an excel sheet. I have found most of the things I am looking for, however I am having some issues getting `ClosedXML` to take care of the number of decimal places as well as rounding the number.

I am currently using `cell.Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 10;`
to get the cell to show a Percentage with 2 decimal places, I would however like to show only 1 decimal place, and the [wiki for `ClosedXML`](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumberFormatId%20Lookup%20Table) only shows percent with 0 or 2 decimal places.

Next when I do not use `ClosedXML` and add the data directly Excel will round the decimal places up, but when I use `ClosedXML` to enter the data the cells do not round up, is there a way to force `ClosedXML` to round for me, or do I need to do that manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you might have to write your own custom `NumberFormatId` according to this SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900397/541208, alternatively, in the [`ClosedXML` docs](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table), it says to add a new `Style`:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Style NumberFormat");

var co = 2;
var ro = 1;

// Using a custom format
ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "123456.789";
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$ #,##0.00";

ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "12.345";
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0000";

// Using a OpenXML's predefined formats
ws.Cell(++ro, co).Value = "12.345";
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 3;

ws.Column(co).AdjustToContents();

workbook.SaveAs("StylesNumberFormat.xlsx");
```

So your custom `NumberFormat` would be something like `0.0%` based on the default formats [listed here:](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table)

```
ws.Cell(ro, co).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";
```

Comment: I missed this as the obvious answer but after looking at it I have changed my format to 'cell.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";' and the single decimal place is taken care of. Thank you. Now to figure out the rounding puzzle.

Comment: I take it back, now with 1 decimal place the number are rounding properly. Thank you again.