# Programmatically set a sheet's format to text before reading the cell contents

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a requirement to read the contents of an excel sheet, write to it and allow for editing and re-importing. The problem I am having is that when user enters a number into the cells in the sheet, the numbers are, on the back, considered indexes on the SharedString table, an effect I do not need. What I would like to do is force the cells in the worksheet to be formatted as text before going ahead to read it. I believe that way, I am sure that my numbers will be treated as Strings. How do I accomplish this please?

I would appreciate examples using the OPENXML library to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be certain that what you retrieve from Excel will be a string is to call Range.Text (which will return the displayed text based on the current format), which can only be retrieved with a single cells.

However if you want to make the format Text, then just call:

```
Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
```

As further details to what I was saying above... Changing the format does not alter the .Value of the cell. Values are generally either Strings, Dates, or Doubles depending on their number format and the contents.

---

**EDIT**
Due to your last comment, I did some additional research for you. However, this is not tested by me. If this does not help you, I recommend updating your question to show what you've tried to help garner more response from the community.

You should be able to utilize the steps listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900397/1316573)(make sure to upvote if it helps you).

The only variation, you should be able to skip creating a [NumberingFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.numberingformat.aspx). When you get to the code:
`cellFormat.NumberFormatId = nf2decimal.NumberFormatId;` instead of the nf2decimal... just use 49. so...
`cellFormat.NumberFormatId = 49;` 49 should correspond to the predefined numeberFormat of @ [according to this source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/e27aaf16-b900-4654-8210-83c5774a179c/)

Comment: Do I call this on the worksheet, the row, or each cell I extract from the row?

Comment: What's this? `Cells.Numberformat` applies to a range or Worksheet. If called on a worksheet like `Worksheet.Cells.Numberformat`, it will affect all cells on the sheet.

Comment: What library are you using there?  I am still yet to find the numberformat property on my cells, and worksheets.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you couldn't access Excel directly. This question may help you: [Applying % number format to a cell value using open xml](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7872116/1316573)

Comment: It seems that form of formatting does not work to solve the problem at all. Some of the values still go to the SharedStringTable which is OK only problem is when I enter number values in my table, they are interepreted as indexes on the ShareString table and that results in bad data being displayed.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions that take advantage of OpenXML?

Answer (score 1):

Like this in VBA:

```
Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: I am working in OPENXML and so, having a hard time finding the above in that library. If in OPENXML, what namespace do I look for this please?