# How to append % symbol in numbers format without multiplying by 100 in ClosedXML

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml, format-string

When I set format of a cell as **%**, and Export it automatically multiply the value with 100 & show the value. So **1.9** becomes **190%**, I have use this code to add Symbol of **%**.

```
worksheet.Cell(2, 2).Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat("0.00%");
```

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: Is your work support standard numeric format strings?

Comment: What do you want as a result exactly?

Comment: It looks like your question has been answered here: [StackOverflow Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872116/applying-number-format-to-a-cell-value-using-openxml)

Comment: @SonerGönül yes support standard numeric format string, and as a result i just want 1.9% instead of 190%.

Comment: Jus a wild guess, try a , instead of a .

Comment: Applied!, got the same..

Comment: had found the solution that you may tried for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally Got a solution by Own.
You can do it in a simple way. If you want to apply it on single cell then do this,

```
worksheet.Cell(9, 10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#,##0.00\\%";
```

And If you want to apply it on a Range of Cells then do this,

```
worksheet.Range(9, 10, 15, 10).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#,##0.00\\%";
```

you can also find more formats [Here](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumberFormatId%20Lookup%20Table&referringTitle=Styles%20-%20NumberFormat/), and also you can find the same from Excel  as well.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me but I used "#,##0.00%" instead of "#,##0.00\%"