# OpenXML 2.0 Gets wrong cell value

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk, excel-2010

I'm having a bit of a problem reading a value from an **Excel** 2010 worksheet.

On a standard Excel 2010 worksheet I have a cell with the currency format with two decimal places and the value `1270,14 €`.

When I read this value on OpenXML 2.0 (C# code) I get `1270.1400000000001` instead of the original `1270.14`.

The same happens with other values on any cell with the same formating.

Get value from cell OpenXML code:

```
private string GetCellValue(string column, int row)
{
    column = column.ToUpper();
    var targetCell = cells.Where(p => p.CellReference == (column + row)).SingleOrDefault();

    var value = String.Empty;

    if (targetCell.DataType != null && targetCell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        var index = int.Parse(targetCell.CellValue.Text);
        value = cellValues[index].InnerText.Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        if (targetCell.CellValue != null)
        {
            value = targetCell.CellValue.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

The specific value passes over the 'if' DataType is not null condition and retrieves the value with the line:

`value = targetCell.CellValue.Text.Trim();`

*How can this be fixed ?*

*Why is this error even possible ?*

Comment: That has nothing to do with OpenXML - it is an inherent problem of using "floating point arithmetic" (on almost all platforms and with almost all languages)... Excel does format the value for display... you could do the same...

Comment: @Yahia - You could be right if that value was a result of some kind of calculation but no. '1270,14' was a keyed in number on a cell pre-formated as currency with Two decimal places. Since I'm not making any type of calculation\formula I don't think the problem of "floating point arithmetic" is present here.

Comment: you just proved my point: the cell is *formatted* as decimal with 2 decimal places... but when you access it from .NET you get a double which in turn is prone to anyting "floating point arithmetic" is!

Answer (score 5):

As the number is stored as double in Excel, you can first parse the string as double, then convert back to string to get the value for display:

```cs
    string s = Convert.ToDouble(value).ToString();
```

Let Microsoft handle its own problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though it may not fit your application, the easiest fix would be simply rounding off the value you get back and assigning it or returning it where applicable. `somevarhere=Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(value), 2)`

Comment: That is a good workaround but the problem is that I don't really process any of the information coming from the excel file meaning I can be reading numbers or simply text and in that case your code will break.

Comment: If you want to match your display to that of Excel, look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730152/what-indicates-an-office-open-xml-cell-contains-a-date-time-value You could format your strings based on the cell formatting. This seems like the most appropriate answer for your application