# read actual value from excel having custom column format

Tags: c#

I have .xlsx file which we read from c# code where we have values like 12.1456 but when we read value from c# code we are getting round value as 12 / 13. Is we have any best way to read file value as it is.

Comment: which api are you using?

Comment: Hi Aesen. i am trying to use with oledb

Comment: Please show us the code you use - provide us with a [mcve]. You can [edit] it into your question. With that information, maybe we can help.

Comment: Excel store in floating-point please check below code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454026/reading-decimal-value-from-an-excel-cell-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores values as a double precision floating point numbers, so many times what you type in to Excel isn't precisely storable as a floating point.